# File Conversion Issue with PDAL

Tags: pdal

Is there any single command line available which converts all the pcd file in a folder into CSV and create individual CSV file for individual pcd file?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a single command. PDAL does not apply multiple operations to data. Users must achieve that themselves with external tools. One could write a bash, powershell, or windows batch script to achieve it with some simple script.